# Reference Architecture Specific Assembly during build time

Tags: .net, assemblies, cpu-architecture

Is it somehow possible to make referenced .net assemblies in a project architecture and/or compile flag specific? E.g. I have several components that are specifically compiled for x86 and another x64 assembly, both containing the same namespaces/functionality etc. However, I want to use the x86 one on x86 machines and the 64bit one on 64bit machines (someAssembly_x86.dll vs someAssembly_x64.dll, both have dependencies to numerous anycpu assemblies).

Is there any way to accomplish this more or less natively (does the msbuild/.csproj file have any sort of compile flag compatibility)?

Comment: Should have searched a little longer, this does the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio