# How can I deploy SQLite in WinRT devices with an ARM CPU?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing a C# Window8 / WinRT app and I'm using SQLite-NET with the sqlite3.dll linked at the bottom of the documentation at

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

My project works fine on my computer, but since sqlite is a non-managed DLL, I wonder what's going to happen when I deploy my app to the app store and someone with an ARM cpu tries to run it. Is it going work? If not, how can I make it work?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not going to work.  You cannot choose a neutral architecture (Any CPU) when there is a C++ component involved.  You will have to compile your SQLite DLL into ARM in order for you to have an ARM version.  If you have a native component, you will submit multiple versions for the Store and the customer will download the correct version for their architecture.

Good blog post on [Windows on the ARM architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. In case someone else runs into this problem: You can use this workaround to select the correct dll: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know is that Microsoft is working with guys from SQLLite and is now officially supported

Comment: I've read something similar in Tim Heuer's Blog, and he is a MS evangelist, but this is far from being official support. Do you have any link with more information regarding this?

Comment: It would be nice to find out how they plan to support these native components

Comment: I think by now its clear that SQLLite is going to be officially supported by Microsoft and your Metro Apps using SQLLite will be certified for Windows Store, I am just beginning to add this to my own opensource project http://metrorssreader.codeplex.com, see http://kennykerr.ca/2012/06/21/sqlite-on-windows-8/