# How to print pdf/image file from Windows 8/C# app

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, microsoft-metro

I have a project that can pick pdf/image file for printing. I tried to find an example but i only found one that print the content of page. Can Windows 8 app print from a file? and How I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing PDF documents from Windows 8 App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533616/printing-pdf-documents-from-windows-8-app)