# Refer both 32-bit and 64-bit dll in .NET Project and Click Once

Tags: .net, dll, clickonce, 32bit-64bit

Can a .NET application/project refer both 32-bit dll and 64-bit dll and at runtime use appropriate one depending on the machine it is being executed on ?

Also would the user downloading the application via Click Once web page get the appropriate dll depending on his/her machine architecture ?

Comment: SetDllDirectory works at Win32-api, CLR doesn't follow it. In my case I am dealing with .NET dll.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find an answer to your problem (which appear to be "yes", but not at Runtime if I understand well the solution) in [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio).