# Conditional use of 32/64 bits for Designer and Build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI Managed Library that I built both for x86 and x64.
I use this library in a C# Project that I am building for Any CPU. And I am using the x64 Version of my C++/CLI Managed Library.

After looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio) where some techniques to build using either the x86 or x64 dlls according the platform of your project.

I wonder, if it is possible to indicate the designer to use the x86 version of my library, while my application could still be using the x64?

Right now my designer shows errors if I try to use in my View Models anything that belongs to the x64 Library.

Comment: @hans if you find the dupe I'll vote to close too.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean that we have been through this before? Are there other questions about this? I couldn't find any.