# equivalent of -march=native for msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, cpu-architecture, compiler-optimization

As far as I know, the compilation option for MSVC that tells the compiler to use special available instruction is /arch. On clang/linux, we can use -march=native to automatically detect the architecture and the "best" instruction sets.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with /arch, i.e. to find the best available argument for this option on the current hardware?

I couldn't find an appropriate option in MSVC documentation. If it does not exist, is there another solution (through CMake for instance)?

Comment: I don't believe this exists.

Comment: My understanding is MSVC is optimized for the Windows platform.  To use special instructions, you would change the optimization level.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51814725/

Answer (score 6):

The default for MSVC is `/arch:SSE2` for x86 and is the implicit default for x64. All versions of Windows 8.1 32-bit or later mandate support for SSE2 to install, and all versions of Windows x64 have to have SSE2 support as part of the definition of the x64 platform.

For MSVC, the only time you use `/arch:` for x86/x64 is if you are selecting `/arch:AVX` or `/arch:AVX2`.

> Technically on MSVC x86 you can use `/arch:IA86` to try to force the use of legacy x87 instructions instead of SSE/SSE2, but that's not a recommended solution or scenario. It also means the code would never match the behavior of x64 which always uses SSE/SSE2.

> For MSVC when targeting the Windows on ARM64 platform, the use of `/arch:arm8.0` or `/arch:arm8.1` determines if the compiler makes use of a CPU instruction for `InterlockedIncrement`. On Windows 11 for ARM64, the whole OS is built using `/arch:arm8.1`. If targeting Windows 10 for ARM64, you should use the default (i.e. `/arch:arm8.0`).

The other switch in use for MSVC is `/favor` which is used for Intel vs. AMD optimization choices. The default is `/favor:BLEND` which is intended to be a good compromise between the two. Typically the only time you use an explicit `/favor` switch is if you are specifically targeting Xbox (`/favor:AMD64`) or Intel ATOM (`/favor:ATOM`).

> For example, for Xbox One you use `/favor:AMD64 /arch:AVX`. For Xbox Series X|S, you use `/favor:AMD64 /arch:AVX2`.

For Clang/Linux the `-march=native` switch, my understanding is that it is taking information from the host CPU to determine which settings to use, which makes sense if you are building code only intended to run on the local machine. That's generally NOT the approach for Windows.

Another difference with Clang `-march` vs. MSVC `/arch` is that if you use explicit intrinsics, Clang *really wants* you to specify a high-enough `-march` to make it valid. MSVC just trusts you know what you are doing if you use a particular intrinsic, and that you will guard the code-path appropriately. You also need to avoid using `/arch:SSE2` with the x64 compiler because it doesn't actually support that option as it's required:

> Since there's not a great way to tell exact target architecture in CMake, I use a build variable set to `x86`, `x64`, `ARM`, or `ARM64` for Ninja scenarios then evaluate it as follows in CMake. If you are using the VS MSBuild generators, you can infer it from the `CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM` variable usually set via `-A` or in recent CMake you can use `CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT`.

```
if(DEFINED VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE)
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH ${VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE})
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM MATCHES "^[Ww][Ii][Nn]32$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH x86)
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM MATCHES "^[Xx]64$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH x64)
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM MATCHES "^[Aa][Rr][Mm]$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH arm)
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM MATCHES "^[Aa][Rr][Mm]64$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH arm64)
elseif(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT MATCHES "^[Ww][Ii][Nn]32$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH x86)
elseif(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT MATCHES "^[Xx]64$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH x64)
elseif(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT MATCHES "^[Aa][Rr][Mm]$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH arm)
elseif(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT MATCHES "^[Aa][Rr][Mm]64$")
    set(DIRECTX_ARCH arm64)
endif()

...

if(NOT (${DIRECTX_ARCH} MATCHES "^arm"))
    if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
        set(ARCH_SSE2 $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/arch:SSE2> $<$<NOT:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:-msse2>)
    else()
        set(ARCH_SSE2 $<$<NOT:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:-msse2>)
    endif()

    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${ARCH_SSE2})
endif()
```

Comment: In the section on `/flavor` it might be worth mentioning `-mtune`

Comment: Worth mentioning that MSVC's `/arch:AVX2` is actually like `gcc -march=x86-64-v3` - it enables AVX2+FMA+BMI2.  Demo of the compiler inventing FMA and BMI1 from "plain" code without intrinsics: https://godbolt.org/z/P5Yxdj4cf

Comment: Yes, GCC/clang `-march=native` detects ISA extensions supported by the host system and enables all of them.  Is *also* detects what CPU it actually is, and enables `-mtune=icelake-client` or `-mtune=znver4` or whatever which can affect instruction-selection choices and for example `-mprefer-vector-width=512` on Zen 4 vs. `256` on other AVX-512 CPUs.  It also detects L1/L2/L3 cache sizes (as inputs for inlining and unrolling heuristics I think?  Or for choosing to use NT stores in big enough loops perhaps?  Not sure if GCC or clang actually do that these days.)

Comment: The cache-size detection is something you get with `-mtune=native` (implied by `-march=native` or manually used) that you might not get with `-mtune=skylake` on a Skylake, I'm not 100% sure; I've never looked into the details.

Comment: MSVC's `-mtune=` equivalent is `/favor:` not `/flavor:`.  https://godbolt.org/z/cx43Kfh8x shows MSVC warn about ignoring `/flavor:ATOM`, but accept `/favor`.