# Compiling for a specific machine on a different machine

Tags: gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization, icc

This might actually be a ridiculous question, but there is so much about compilers/compiling that I don't understand. I'm aware of the concepts of [cross compiling, cross-native compiling, etc.](https://build-gdc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cross-Compiler%20Basics/) However, I am unaware of what applies for my scenario:

What I want to do is this.

Say I have two computers with different hardware, **A** and **B**.

Suppose that the only similarities between **A** and **B** I know for sure are:

1. Both have some Intel processor capable of 64 bit computing.
2. Both run Windows 10, and thus can access Linux through other means (e.g. WSL).
3. Both **A** and **B** have all the programs necessary to compile (arbitrary) code.

Suppose that I also have administrative access to **A** (i.e. I can do/run/install whatever I want to/on it). This is *not* the case for **B**.

In addition, (this may be irrelevant), **A** can be accessed physically (and remotely if necessary). **B** can *only* be accessed remotely (via SSH, RDP, etc.)

---

Now say I want to compile some arbitrarily complex C/C++ code *optimized specifically* for the hardware on *A* with some compiler. For example, I believe [`-march=native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800242/equivalents-to-gcc-clangs-march-native-in-other-compilers) can achieve this if I use `gcc` *on* **A**.

However, say **A** is special, and that its processing power cannot be "wasted" on compiling, for it has more important tasks to do. In other words, I do *not* want to go through the time and power consuming process of compilation *on* **A**.

Instead, I want to do this compilation for **A** *on* **B**.

How can I obtain an end result equivalent to a `"-march=native"` compile done *on* **A** (*if* `gcc` is used)? In other words, how can I compile code *on* **B** optimized *precisely* for the hardware on **A**?

For `gcc`, is it as simple as [finding the equivalent flags for `-march=native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470257/how-to-see-which-flags-march-native-will-activate) *on* **A** to then run execute on **B**? If so, is there a way to streamline this process and if not, how can it be done (if at all?).

Can the process be done with [compilers other than gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800242/equivalents-to-gcc-clangs-march-native-in-other-compilers) (namely, the Visual C++ and Intel C++ compilers)?

Comment: If both systems have the same type of CPU and run the same OS, then you don't need cross-compilation as the target for both systems will be the same. If you want optimizations specific to a *variant* of the target CPU you can specify it with `-march` (and other [optimization flags and options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know architecture of destination server (A in your case) just pass it to gcc on B as -march.

Example

A architecture is skylake

so on B use

`gcc -march=skylake ..... (rest of the flags)`

if A is ryzen

`gcc -march=znver1 ..... (rest of the flags)`

and then copy files from B to A.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Compiler can be used for generating executables targeting other architectures either by using GCC compatible option which is -march or ICC specific option which is -x. These options are documented at https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-x-qx and https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-march.