# Is it possible to mix x64/x86 in a C# Project?

Tags: c#, wcf, x86, 64-bit

We have a WebService that's been running for a while, there's about 6~ projects on it.
Recently, we had to support a C++ 32 bit library, I tested and I had to set the project's target platform to x86 or I'd get the `BadImageFormatException`. So this new project is set to compile on x86, but everything else is set to AnyCPU.

After publishing the WebService, I get the error `Unable to find ?.dll` when calling the function.

Is there anyway I can add this new project as x86 without having to set my WCF to x86 as well, or am I doing something wrong and this should've worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but *all* binaries (.exe-s and .dll-s) must share the same target platform for it to work. You cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process or the other way around.

If you're hosting your web service under IIS, the target platform of the app pool determines what kind of DLL-s you can load.

If you have exported functions in your unmanaged DLL-s, your P/Invoke declarations must also match the target platform - specifically, if you pass pointers, those will have to be correctly mapped to 32/64-bit pointers. (Usually `IntPtr` takes care of this.) P/Invoke declarations really turn into possible problems if you support both platforms with a single source base (compiled into platform-specific binaries).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may also need to deal with handling platform-specific references. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio) has more detail about that.