# Can a unit test project reference a different external DLL than the prod project?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, shared-libraries

I have these projects/DLLs:

- `mylib` project - the project with logic I'm testing
- `mylib_test` project - the nunit test project testing `mylib`
- `otherlib.dll` - a 3rd party DLL that `mylib` uses
- `otherlib_mock.dll` - a mock of `otherlib.dll` that I want to use when testing. It contains all the types that are in `otherlib.dll` with the same interfaces, except that it always returns mock data instead of actually doing the work that `otherlib.dll` does.

I want that `mylib` will use `otherlib.dll` in regular operation but when unit tests are run from `mylib_test` - `otherlib_mock.dll` will be used by `mylib`.

Currently, all the types are in the same namespace as `otherlib.dll` so if I modify `mylib` to reference `otherlib_mock.dll` instead of `otherlib.dll` - everything works with the mock types. Can somehow do this automatically for testing and not for regular operation?

Option 2 is: I have the code of `otherlib_mock.dll`. I could change its namespace to be different than `otherlib.dll` and then I could reference them both in `mylib`. Now, I toggle between the mocked and non-mocked behavior by switching between the namespaces. Can I put the `using` lines in `#if` and `#else` so that I use the `otherlib.dll` namespace in regular operation and the `otherlib_mock.dll` namespace when running tests?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate to be solved through dependency injection. You should reference both dlls in different namepspaces, and then in your test library, inject the test library, and in production code, inject the real one.

Comment: I know how to inject code, how do I inject a library?

Comment: Ideally, the calls to this library should have been written against a contract, so that injection would switch between two referenced libraries. But if you do not want to change the code, and then I guess dynamically loading the assembly should work.

Comment: Alternatively, this question already explains a similar situation. Instead of architecture, you can define custom properties in your projects. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted by adding a solution configuration and a project configuration to `mylib` called Test. I now need to use them when I compile `mylib_test` in order for `mylib` to include `otherlib_mock`. It's not 100% elegant but it gets the job done. Thanks