# Reference correct dll file at realeas?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a reference to a `32 bit dll` file in my `Windows Service application`.

I'm using `Any CPU` during the `debug` and at this point the regular `32 bit version` of the dll file works fine. But, when I built it in `64 bits` and installed on a `64 Windows Service` I get bad image when using method from the `dll file`.

I have a `64 bit version` of the `dll` file but it does not work in my debug mode.

How do I make it use the 64 at release and the 32 in debug without manually remove and add the reference?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4270930/891715

Comment: This hack looks really interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You have to compile it for one or the other.  If you reference your 32-bit DLL, you must set the application to target x86 both for debugging and for release.  If you want it to run in full 64-bit mode, you need to reference your 64-bit DLL and set the application to target x64 in debug mode and in release mode as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile two versions of the binary for each arch.