# Vb.net project reference libraries locations for different configuration

Tags: vb.net, reference, msbuild

Related: [Conditionally use 32/64 bit reference when building in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio/3833444#3833444)

Normally when you add vb.net projects as reference in the same solution there is a reference added with a hint location. now in C# as far as i remember it adds it based on architecture. Why not in Vb.net or am i just doing it wrong. Check the related question.

```
<Reference Include="MyComAssembly.Interop">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\x86\MyComAssembly.Interop.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
<Reference Include="MyComAssembly.Interop">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\x64\MyComAssembly.Interop.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

To clarify i do get the entry but its not architecture based by default. The related question does talk about manually editing the file but I am trying to understand why its not happening automatically for VB.net compared to C#. Is there any open feature request as well.

Edit on 6/6/2017
for Vb.net it shows the references correctly as explained in first response, but why doesn't a COM reference work in the same way.

Comment: I don't think, you have a point here. Both work the same. Add "Condition" to item group and it will work as long as you have that configuration in your project.

Comment: my question was why its not being added automatically. Manually works fine. The related question has a long discussion on this. Wonder why MSFT cant just do the same for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as answer, because I need to show some code here

You said:

> *Normally when you add vb.net projects as reference in the same solution there is a reference added with a hint location*

Answer:

No. Project reference is created as following

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
  <Project>{7316c328-7716-4b5c-b736-f5811c764158}</Project>
  <Name>MyProject</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Your XML shows DLL reference. If you reference from DLL, you get the hint.

And the `ItemGroup`condition is not added by default, not in C#, not in VB. This is something you do manually. I am telling you this as build master who constantly configures projects and solutions.

Comment: You reasoning seems to be correct but let me verify that as well.well maybe i am mistaken

Comment: Correcting my question as well. I agree with your response.