# Visual studio IDE change references upon changing configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is there a way where I can change references using the configuration manager?  I have a third party DLL which for some reason is split in two folders:  x86, x64.
example the x86 bit would be in:
c:\progra~1\myAddin\x86\someDll.dll
while the x64 would be:
c:\progra~1\myAddin\x64\someDll.dll

I would need some option from the VS IDE that when I switch to 'debug' configuration it would change to x86 and when I switch to 'release' it would change to x64 dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is going to lead to issues. Switching between debug and release shouldn't change the platform you are targeting. You should be switching references only when the platform changes (this is the box to the right of the configuration).

I have not found a good way to manage this via the IDE, but you can easily manage this by modifying the project file directly. Take a look at [Conditionally use 32/64 bit reference when building in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Quote: "Your approach is going to lead to issues. Switching between debug and release shouldn't change the platform you are targeting. ".  I tend to disagree here. for example, I use debug -> x86 which allows me to change code during runtime and then switch to release -> Any CPU to issue an architecture independent exe. Thanks for the link btw, it seems a bit long-winded when considering that I have multiple files not just one as I mentioned.