# How to fix error `exited with code 4` Build Any (x86 and x64) Winform Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Goal: I would like to build a Winform application which can support x86 and x64. Normally, there is no problem if I build x86 only but

1. A function of this Winform application depends on licensed external library that which some users installed x86, some user installed x64 version, and some user install both --> If I set my Winform application as x86, it will try to run x86 on licensed external library --> error
2. Winform application uses a SAP Connector 3.0 library which SAP ships the library in 2 different package x64 and x86

Workaround/Current method:  I do everything in x86 with SAP x86 library --> copy project --> change x64 --> change SAP reference to its x64 library

This causing more works + the application changes quite often and I wish I could just build 1.

What I have tried:
I followed this [Q-A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio) **Resolution of correct x86/x64-dlls at runtime**

(1) I got `exited with code 4` when I try add this to post-build (also pre-build) events

```
xcopy /E /H /R /Y /I /D $(SolutionDir)\x86 $(TargetDir)\x86
xcopy /E /H /R /Y /I /D $(SolutionDir)\x64$(TargetDir)\x64
```

I am not sure if this is problem:  I also use SQLite in my application and it already has 2 folders x64 and x86 created at the release directory.

Comment: Is the missing space in the last line a typo?

Comment: Did you try to use the Configuration Manager and create two configurations? One for x86 with the x86 references and one for x64 for the x64 references?

Comment: @Steve - yes, it was a typo, accidentally when I tried to make post nicer.

Comment: @Steve - that what I am current doing that but I have to re-reference the SAP library manually when there is code change.

Comment: @Steve - I just found out that I could manually copy the SAP dlls to x86 and x64 to the "Any" release folder, at least I will not need to build 2 different projects (x64 and x86)

Comment: Look in the Output window for the actual error message that xcopy produced.  "Access denied" would be likely, temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product to see if that's the cause.  Or whatever "copy protect" did to prevent copying.